Is it full or partial specifialization if all template parameters are specialized, but the specified type is itself a template?
Is the last example here, where one_t is specialized for types std::vector<T> for any T a full or partial specialization?
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct one_t {};

// clearly a full specialization
template<>
struct one_t<int> {};

// full or partial?
template<typename U>
struct one_t<std::vector<U>> {};


Full specialization needs to be such: template <> declaration , does not match that pattern, so what is the question?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Can your last example be specialized further (for example, defining a specialization for one_t<std::vector<int>>)? If it can, how would you justify calling the last example's specialization "full"?

@ÖöTiib the question was whether the last example above is a full specialization. Your observation would have made a good answer, minus the snark.
